# Finish updating UI before execute code

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface

I have a dialog and I'm changing some view's text on it. After that, I'm creating a new thread and it runs its own code. But my dialog's UI won't get updated. It waits till the code in the thread is finished. I want to update my dialog's UI, then run the codes in the thread. Here is my code:

//Dialog is being initialized long before this code. This code is in a button's click.

```
formatBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
okBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
noUSBmsg.setText(R.string.formatting);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       try {
            Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
            OutputStream os = proc.getOutputStream();
            os.write(("mkfs.vfat /dev/block/sd*;").getBytes("ASCII"));
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                proc.waitFor();
                if (TransferData.CheckUSB()) {
                    Toast.makeText(DataTransferActivity.this,DataTransferActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.formatSuc),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(DataTransferActivity.this,DataTransferActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.formatFail),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                noUsbDlg.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("format disk: "+ e.toString());
            }

        }
    }).run();
```

Probably something is blocking the UI's thread. But I don't understand it. The second code block is running in a different thread. How could it possibly block the UI's thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well of course it does. Look carefully: you're executing `Thread.run()` manually, so it runs on the same thread that's creating the thread object [UI thread, that is, hence the blockage]. `.run()` doesn't start the new thread, `.start()` does :)

More on the topic here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html